# SAMLException: "Assertion invalidated by missing Audience Restriction" when started from identity provider

Tags: java, saml-2.0, opensaml, spring-security-saml2

`SAMLException`: with the following error  "Assertion invalidated by missing Audience Restriction", when I try to do saml login and started from identity provider site with out initiate the request form  service provider site.

my SP meta data :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<md:EntityDescriptor ID="urn_test_system_stag_sp_test" entityID="urn:test:system:stag:sp:test"
                     xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata">
    <md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false"
                        protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                Location="https://mytestsite/samlSlo"/>
        <md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect"
                                Location="https://mytestsite/samlSlo"/>

        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                                     Location="https://mytestsite/samlAcs?sp=test" index="0"
                                     isDefault="true"/>
        <md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact"
                                     Location="https://mytestsite/samlAcs?sp=test"
                                     index="1"/>
    </md:SPSSODescriptor>
</md:EntityDescriptor>
```

the Exception that I have :

```
       2018-02-15 15:30:24,356 org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.marlin.action.sso.saml2.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:61)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.marlin.action.TstsFilter.doFilter(TstsFilter.java:79)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter3(InitSessionFilter.java:226)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter2(InitSessionFilter.java:160)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter(InitSessionFilter.java:95)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.modules.servlet.ForwardFilter.doFilter(ForwardFilter.java:230)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.modules.servlet.FakeIpFilter.doFilter(FakeIpFilter.java:43)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.modules.servlet.ClientIpFilter.doFilter(ClientIpFilter.java:114)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.test.mycode.frontend.filter.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.java:98)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1349)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,356     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1305)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1289)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1197)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:993)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357 Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Assertion invalidated by missing Audience Restriction
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionConditions(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:431)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:303)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
2018-02-15 15:30:24,357     ... 50 more
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939 org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Response doesn't have any valid assertion which would pass subject validation
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:229)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:87)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.marlin.action.sso.saml2.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:61)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:184)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.marlin.action.TstsFilter.doFilter(TstsFilter.java:79)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter3(InitSessionFilter.java:226)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter2(InitSessionFilter.java:160)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.mycode.access.InitSessionFilter.doFilter(InitSessionFilter.java:95)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.modules.servlet.ForwardFilter.doFilter(ForwardFilter.java:230)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.modules.servlet.FakeIpFilter.doFilter(FakeIpFilter.java:43)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.modules.servlet.ClientIpFilter.doFilter(ClientIpFilter.java:114)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.test.mycode.frontend.filter.HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.doFilter(HttpSecurityHeadersFilter.java:98)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1349)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1305)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1289)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1197)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:993)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939 Caused by: org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Assertion invalidated by missing Audience Restriction
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertionConditions(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:431)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.verifyAssertion(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:303)
2018-02-15 15:30:25,939     at org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.processAuthenticationResponse(WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl.java:214)
    ... 50 more
```

Can any one help me on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the issue because I did not start my request form service provider site (my site) the saml request that contains the "saml2 Issuer" so the identity provider site will not know about the request sender and after successful login  on their  side the `AudienceRestriction` will not included in the response and the `SAMLException` will be thrown

As solution I asked Idinety provider to add the following `AudienceRestriction` permanently  :

```
    <saml:Conditions NotBefore="2018-02-19T18:51:12.596Z" NotOnOrAfter="2018-02-19T19:51:12.596Z">
        <saml:AudienceRestriction>
            <saml:Audience>urn:test:system:stag:sp:test</saml:Audience>
        </saml:AudienceRestriction>
    </saml:Conditions>
```